# Google Font not showing up

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts

So I checked and this doesnt work on chrome and safari, haven't checked other browsers.

Ok so the problem is I am trying to use a google font but my css will not recognize, I can only manually change it (and get it to work) when I use chrome developer tools. By unchecking this:

```
font-family: Circular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
```

which has a line through it. So I am assuming it is somehow overriding the google font I am trying to import and use. Or it could be something with the react app, I can't figure it out.

The rest of my code is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@600&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Web site created using create-react-app"
/>
```

and (CSS)

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@600&display=swap');

  .booking_info {
padding-left: 130px;
padding-top: 50px;
 }

 .booking_heading {
padding-bottom: 20px;
font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace !important;
   }

 .booking_heading > h2 {
font-weight: 200;
  }
```

Thanks, I just want to be able to use Source Code Pro font.

Comment: The answer does not lie within the snippets you posted. You are likely importing something that adds the rule. A quick fix would be to add more specificity than it has. A better fix would be to figure out what is adding that rule.

Comment: I have been importing Material UI tools in other components, but I haven't added anything else to the html, so I am not sure if that could be it. How would I go about adding more specificity than what I have done? I am open to resources to learn as well.